# Convert data from excel to a list

Tags: list-manipulation, import, excel

I have imported a set of rows from a column of an Excel sheet as follows:

```
datFPS = Import["gis-cc13 s-fps-200solx24sim-table.xlsx", {"Data", 1, 
Range[8, 31], 18}];
```

The problem is the format of `datFPS` is:

```
{[[94 76 7 4 1] [3 1 5 98 100] ...]] [[23 22 11 45 7]...]]...]]}
```

This is several blocks of 5 numbers, all into `[` and `]`  corresponding to each row of the excel. If I do

```
Head[datFPS] = List
```

but I would like a common list of Mathematica which would be

```
{{94,76,7,4,1},{3,1,5,98,100}, {...},...{...}}
```

If `datFPS` was a `String` probably I could make `StringReplace[]` but is not the case.

Is there any way of converting `datFPS` to a list with braces and with comma separations?.

Thank you very much for your help

Regards

Comment: Perhaps you can add a link to the data? Or a relevant subset of it.

Comment: @Kuba I know the best way is to import as a String but if I use `"String"` instead `"Data"` in the `Import[]` it does not work. After the import as "Data" `ToString[]`does not work either.

Comment: @FredikD can you tell me more about how to get that link work? Thanks

Comment: @Kuba Yes, the problem is that when I import the data Mathematica keeps all into a `List`, `{[[2 3 4 5 6] [.....]]....]]}`.

Comment: If `Import` is giving you a list that contains a single string, like this, `s = {"[[94 76 7 4 1][3 1 5 98 100]]"}`, then you may be able to convert the string using a command like this:  `StringReplace[ First@s, {"][" -> "},{", "[" -> "{", "]" -> "}",    " " -> ","}] // ToExpression`

Comment: @LouisB Mathematica gives me `s = {[[94 76 7 4 1][3 1 5 98 100]]}`, no quotations. Do you know how to add those quotations?

Comment: @LouisB Your code works for me. Thank you very much for your help